# How to synchronize Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have three graphs:

1. A line graph time series with only 1 line on it
2. A line graph time series with n lines on it (n could be 5 could be 50)
3. A histogram (actually a stacked column chart)

Graph 1 & 2 have the same timeseries axis and therefore they should have a shared zoom (accomplished) and same tooltip.

I have used this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/

and this jquery: [Highcharts Synchronized charts display tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437297/highcharts-synchronized-charts-display-tooltip)

to get exactly what I wanted for graph 1 & 2.

However when I added graph 3 a few strange things happened:

- The tooltip is now shared with the histogram (it shouldn't be -- histograms aren't time-series)
- The x-zoom now zooms on the histogram creating a time-series axis?
- The shared tooltip doesn't work between graph 1 & 2 now

The perfect solution would be to have a histogram that also filtered as the histogram is measured off graph 1. (NB: lots of data is clipped for the jsfiddle)

```html
pretend this is a code snippet so I can link jsfiddle
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cj2tdy7v/1/

Comment: Hi @j w, Some of the methods are globally overwritten for all of your charts. You need to add an exception for the last chart. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w71zepvy/

Comment: @ppotaczek thanks, that worked! However, the 2nd graph syncs the tooltip with the first graph but not the other way around -- do you know why?

Comment: @j w, It is because you are looking for a point only in the first series: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/apLbh1jq/